# In Xcode, UIActivityViewController does not display any options as in sharing on social media such as sharing on Facebook, Twitter, etc

Tags: swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I tried including `UIActivityViewController` in my Xcode project (swift), but as I ran the app in the simulator, the `UIActivityViewController` didn't include any options of sharing the content (I thought once you include it you can get all the options such as "share on Facebook" and "share on Twitter"

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func shareTextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let text = "This is some text that I want to share."


        let textToShare = [ text ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash



        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    @IBAction func shareImageButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let image = UIImage(named: "Portrait")


        let imageToShare = [ image! ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash


                self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here's what appeared in the debug console:

> 2017-04-05 18:32:34.902268-0700 AA[26541:4024236] [MC] System group
>   container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/cuiboy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/55F2DE69-127A-4F0E-871F-4E431586D8AF/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   objc[26541]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x11a182cc0) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x119f996f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   2017-04-05 18:32:35.141398-0700 AA[26541:4024236] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType:
>   com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter => com.apple.share.Twitter.post
>   2017-04-05 18:32:35.141532-0700 AA[26541:4024236] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType:
>   com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook =>
>   com.apple.share.Facebook.post 2017-04-05 18:32:35.141629-0700
>   AA[26541:4024236] [core] SLComposeViewController
>   extensionIdentifierForActivityType:
>   com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToWeibo => com.apple.share.SinaWeibo.post
>   2017-04-05 18:32:35.141728-0700 AA[26541:4024236] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType:
>   com.apple.UIKit.activity.TencentWeibo =>
>   com.apple.share.TencentWeibo.post 2017-04-05 18:32:35.141801-0700
>   AA[26541:4024236] [core] SLComposeViewController
>   extensionIdentifierForActivityType:
>   com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFlickr => com.apple.share.Flickr.post
>   2017-04-05 18:32:35.141904-0700 AA[26541:4024236] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType:
>   com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToVimeo => com.apple.share.Vimeo.post
>   2017-04-05 18:32:35.325040-0700 AA[26541:4024236] [MC] Reading from
>   private effective user settings.

Does anybody know what is wrong? What can I do to make Facebook and twitter and other social media options appear in the activity view controller?
Thanks

Comment: I think these options will appear on the real device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it coded correctly.

There is an `excludedActivityTypes` property where you can code what you want to *exclude*, but with nothing excluded whatever is available on a device will appear (meaning if FaceBook or Twitter isn't on the device, it won't). Since you are using the simulator, these options do not appear.

On a side note, the debug console implies you are probably seeing a lot of "info" you may wish to remove. If so, choose your build scheme (upper left in Xcode), choose "Edit Scheme", and add the following environment variable:

Name: **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE**

Value: **disable**

Comment: Thank you so much!! I simulated it on my iPhone and it worked perfectly. Very much appreciated